# How to setup DMZ with Airport behind a router (double NAT issue)?

Tags: network, airport

My cable provider shipped a new modem which includes WLAN, and thus also a router. It hands out 192.168.0.X adresses via DHCP.

My Airport's WAN side is connected to this router, and gets an address out of the above range. The ISP's router has no address reservation facility, so the address that the Airport gets can vary.

The Airport is configured to hand out 192.168.243.X addresses via it's own DHCP server. As expected it complains about "double NAT". For the moment I have fixed the issue by disabling the ISP's router and WLAN completely (bridge mode).

However, I'd actually like to use the feature. My desired setup would be:

- ISP's Router
- Airport, using e.g. 192.168.0.10
- Web Server, opening port 80, using e.g. 192.168.0.20. The ISP's router supports port forwarding, so I can do this.

On the Airport's LAN side, I'd like to span an independent 192.168.243.x subnet, that cannot be reached from the web server. In a way, the web server would be in a "DMZ", isolated from the rest of my home network.

The problem is: The Airport doesn't let me do this! When I connect any device to the LAN side of the Airport, I get a 192.168.0.x address from the ISP's router, and not a 192.168.243.x address from the Airport. The Airport acts like it is in bridge mode, even though it isn't.

How can I set this up the way I want to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the box, the Airport (and Apple's Time Capsule) insist that there not be two NAT/DHCP devices chained in a row. You're trying to do this, one being your broadband router, and the other your Airport. In this situation, the Airport will insist on being in bridging mode and letting the broadband router be the DHCP server.

The Airport detects this situation by looking at the IP address it gets. If it is one in a number of known ranges like 192.168.x.x, 172.x.x.x, or 10.x.x.x, it will balk.

So the way you get around this is by having your broadband router give out addresses in a range that's safe but not knows as a "private" address range. I found an article [1] recommending a block of addresses designated for "testing" purposes in the Amateur Packet Radio network (AMPRNet). The range is 44.128.x.x.  I set up my broadband router to use that range, and my TimeCapsule is happy to provide NAT as well. Problem solved.

[1] http://www.wa4dsy.com/robot/ooma-airport-hack

Comment: Thanks, good hint! I can't test it, unfortunately. I got a new router from the ISP which has very limited settings. It only allows 192.168.0.x, nothing else. Maybe it's time to start dealing with IPv6...

Comment: I suppose you could put a vanilla router in between the broadband router and your Airport to solve that problem... :) (you'd suffer some extra latency.)

Answer (score 0):

Turn of the DHCP server on your ISP's router. It might be answering faster than the AirPort DHCP server.

Comment: Thanks! The ISPs DHCP server would not be reachable by the clients behind the Airport, so it couldn't answer at all.